Django issues after deployment on AppEngine
I have a django app that i have it deployed on Google Cloud AppEngine using gunicorn. I now need to support WebSockets, so i am using it with UvicornWorker. The issue is that on Log Explorer it says that the app is listening on port :8080, log: Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080, but when i make a request to the service {gcpProjectId}.uc.r.appspot.com/ , it's never returning. So basically is never reaching the API level. It is working all correctly locally though, both API and WebSocket, but its not working when deployed to AppEngine.
here's my asgi.py
import os

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_app.settings')

django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()


def create_application():
    import shopkit.routing
    return ProtocolTypeRouter({
        "http": django_asgi_app,
        "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                shopkit.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
            )
        )
    })


# This is the ASGI application to be used by Uvicorn when not using --factory
application = create_application()

app.yaml
runtime: python
env: flex
instance_class: B4_1G

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT my_app.asgi:application -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --workers 8 --threads 4 --timeout 0 --keep-alive 65 --log-level info

runtime_config:
  operating_system: "ubuntu18"
  runtime_version: "3.9"

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

network:
  session_affinity: true

readiness_check:
  check_interval_sec: 10
  timeout_sec: 10
  failure_threshold: 10
  success_threshold: 2
  app_start_timeout_sec: 600

env_variables:
  ENV_NAME: prod

My old entrypoint command was
gunicorn my_app.wsgi:application --workers 4 --threads 4 --timeout 120 --max-requests 100 --log-file -


As stated here check the logs for each module, see log messages from non-default module not showing up in console.
